# Why my MySQL table comments the lines where I insert a PHP code? How to fix it? I want to store PHP code inside a MySQL Table and call it back

Tags: php, mysql

Let's suppose that in order to call the content a of particular table column in a database I do:

```
<?php 
....
$content = $row['table_column_name'];
echo $content; 
?>
```

What I want is to store a PHP code in this particular MySQL table column. To do so, I access PHPMyAdmin, click on my database, edit the table column and add the following:

```
<?php echo 'hello'; ?>
```

When I save it an check the result on my website, I don't see anything. If I inspect my source code, it shows:

```
<!-- ?php echo 'hello'; ?-->
```

This somehow makes sense because to call the content I use $content, in other words the code looks like:

```
<?php 
...
<?php echo 'hello'; ?>
?>
```

How do you resolve this? I also read that < symbol is automatically considered a tag and maybe that's another reason why it automatically comments my line. I'm a bit confused..What I really want is **to store PHP code in the database and call it back to the webpage with a mysqli_query** How can I achieve this? Thanks

Comment: You want to insert into database php code and later execute it? What framework are you using?

Comment: Check the contents of the database (using a client different than PhpMyAdmin), and get the cause of this problem by checking if PhpMyAdmin is storing the wrong info, of if your website is showing the wrong info. (I suspect your website is the problem)

Comment: You hardly give any detail, but my educated guess is that you print raw PHP as-is in the middle of an HTML document and then check the browser developer tools to inspect the DOM tree. Since PHP is not HTML, the browser does its best to compose valid HTML from what it's provided.

Comment: No Framework used. Direct inline coding. My file is index.php so I don't know why the browser would assume that as html, because I have additional php lines written in the file and they work fine, only the one that is called from the mysql table column is commented... :(

Comment: I think I know what is the problem but I don't know how to solve it (you can check my updated question). Mainly I use echo $content; to call the content but this variable also has another echo (php code within php code :/). I don't know how can I go over this.

Comment: @statsconchris Why do you want to have PHP code in the content? Is it possible to have simple text tokens instead you can replace with `str_replace()` instead? Something like "Hello {USERNAME}" and then you use `str_replace()` to replace that token with the username of the current user?

Comment: str_replace() doesn't work. I want to create a file example.php that calls and RUNS different php examples, so I thought of storing these examples in a database and just by the id call them in example.php. in other words i want one single file to store many php code examples. unluckily so far it seems that i need one file for each example but that's a lot, the database would be the solution to me but I'm stuck